# Cleft sentence: All I needed was to eat / What I enjoy is eating

Tags: cleft-constructions

Can I check I understand this correctly:

What + subject + verb + is/was + verb in matching verb form

Let me explain:

I enjoy going for a walk. (enjoy + gerund)
What I enjoy is going for a walk.

I avoid using too much petrol. (avoid + gerund)
What I avoid is using too much petrol.

She needs to go home now! (need + infinitive)
What she needs is to go home now.

Is that correct or is it always the infinitive in this type of cleft sentence?
Eg.
What I avoid is to use too much petrol.
What I enjoy is to cycle.

Basic grammar terms would be appreciated in answers. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your examples with gerund-participial (_ing_) clauses are fine. Incidentally, unlike your examples with "what", the one with "all" is not a pseudo-cleft construction.     .

Comment: I'm not sure the "cleft sentence" is relevant here. It's always *I NEED **to go** home* and *I AVOID **staying** too late*. Or with some verbs, either form is possible; *I LIKE **to watch** movies* and *I LIKE **watching** movies* are both fine - and that's still the case with ***What** I like is **to watch / watching** movies*

Answer (score 1):

> What I avoid is to use too much petrol.  What I enjoy is to cycle.

I don't find these grammatical.

Like you explain, ***enjoy*** and ***avoid*** take a gerund as a compliment. It is also true in the WH-cleft construction. We can put an -ing verb in the Subject Noun Phrase to check. And if there is an -ing verb in the Subject Noun Phrase, the predicative complement should match it.
Thus:

> What I enjoy (**doing**) is **going** for a walk.

> What I avoid (**doing**) is **using** too much petrol.

Answer (score 1):

The rules of what verb forms to use remain the same when you use a cleft sentence.

So if you need a gerund in the standard sentence form, you also need a gerund in the cleft form, and same goes for infinitives, base forms, and so on.

Forming a cleft sentence is just a matter of rearranging the original words around the necessary bits to make it cleft, not changing the forms.

Answer (score -1):

Either is acceptable. In everyday speech the gerund versions are probably more common.

Comment: -1 Do you believe "*What I avoid is to use too much petrol*" and "*What I enjoy is to cycle.*" are good grammar??